# Slice lists of list in python when list starts with specific element and end with specific element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, backend

i want to slice list of list when list starts with specific element and ends with specific element such as

*Table: Table_%d i don't want this in list.
*Table: Table_1 is empty most of time.

```
"Table: Table_1" = []
"Table: Table_2"= [abc]
"Table: Table_3"=[xyz]
"Table: Table_4"=[pqr]
```

example Lists of List below (input):

```
[['Table: Table_1'], ['ITEM DESCRIPTION CODE ', 'QTY SUPPLIED ', 'UNIT PRICE ', 'TOTAL ', 'None'], ['CHEM101JUM 750ml Ramset Chemset 101 Jumbo ', '7 ', '$66.00 ', '$462.00 ', 'None'], ['Returned for Credit when 258252 was delivered/Confirmed by Jeremy ', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'Subtotal: ', '$462.00 ', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'GST: ', '$46.20 ', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'Total (Inc GST): ', '$508.20 ', 'None'], ['Table: Table_2'], ['Order Date: ', 'Delivery Date: ', 'Purchase Order # ', 'Customer Acc: ', 'Contact Name: ', 'None'], ['27/03/2020 ', '27/03/2020 ', 'CREDIT Refer 255247 ', 'CU 13577 ', 'Peter 0422 861 935 ', 'None'], ['Table: Table_3'], ['Customer: ', 'Deliver To: ', 'None'], ['AMAC NSW Pty Ltd - CREDIT CARD Payment ', 'AMAC NSW Pty Ltd - CREDIT CARD Payment ', 'None'], ['ABN 51 151 195 836 ', '52 Peronne Av ', 'None'], ['Unit 2', ' 58 C Consul Road Narraweena NSW 2099 ', 'Clontarf NSW ', 'None']]
```

Expected Output

```
 Table: Table_1 = [['ITEM DESCRIPTION CODE ', 'QTY SUPPLIED ', 'UNIT PRICE ', 'TOTAL ', 'None'], ['CHEM101JUM 750ml Ramset Chemset 101 Jumbo ', '7 ', '$66.00 ', '$462.00 ', 'None'], ['Returned for Credit when 258252 was delivered/Confirmed by Jeremy ', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'Subtotal: ', '$462.00 ', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'GST: ', '$46.20 ', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'Total (Inc GST): ', '$508.20 ', 'None']]
Table: Table_2 =[['Order Date: ', 'Delivery Date: ', 'Purchase Order # ', 'Customer Acc: ', 'Contact Name: ', 'None'], ['27/03/2020 ', '27/03/2020 ', 'CREDIT Refer 255247 ', 'CU 13577 ', 'Peter 0422 861 935 ', 'None']]
Table: Table_3= [['Customer: ', 'Deliver To: ', 'None'], ['AMAC NSW Pty Ltd - CREDIT CARD Payment ', 'AMAC NSW Pty Ltd - CREDIT CARD Payment ', 'None'], ['ABN 51 151 195 836 ', '52 Peronne Av ', 'None'], ['Unit 2', ' 58 C Consul Road Narraweena NSW 2099 ', 'Clontarf NSW ', 'None']]
```

Expecting solution updating this code

```
def yield_subgroups(group, subgroup_test):
    subgroup = []

    for i, j in zip_longest(group, islice(group, 1, None)):
        if subgroup_test(i, j):
            yield subgroup
            subgroup = []
        else:
            subgroup.append(i)

    yield subgroup
```

Comment: You have strings and lists on the left side of assignment statements. That's not a good sign.

Comment: Please check @TigerhawkT3

Comment: You still have grossly incorrect syntax in your code, with no sign that you've done any programming. I get the distinct impression that you haven't learned any programming yet and you're trying to get us to do a task that was given to you for some reason.

Comment: How did you try solving it?

Comment: @lllrnr101 trying with this function yield_subgroups

Comment: what is subgroup_test?

Comment: Why don't you iterate on the list, whenever you see Table, start a new list and keep appending till next occurence of table. The update your vars() with that info.

Comment: @lllrnr101 - `yield_subgroups` is taken from https://gist.github.com/seanpianka/1e65b89e5e09f245a07f4d668cb3a44c

Answer (score -1):

There is another solution not updating that code:

```
def print_subgroups(group):
    subgroup = []
    subgroup_temp = []
    
    for i in range(0,len(group)):
        if i == 0:
            subgroup = group[0]
            print(subgroup[0] + " = [")
        elif i != len(group)-1:
            subgroup_temp = group[i]
            for j in subgroup_temp:
                if subgroup_test(j):
                    subgroup.append(j)
            print(subgroup + ", ")
        else:
            subgroup_temp = group[i]
            for j in subgroup_temp:
                if subgroup_test(j):
                    subgroup.append(j)
            print(subgroup + "]")
```